# How do I turn off dSYM files when running C++ files from Visual Studio Code using the Clang++ compiler?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, clang++, dsym

When I ⌘⇧B to build the file, it makes both a Unix Executable, and a .dSYM file. As I don't do iOS dev, is there a way to turn this behaviour off?

The file hierarchy is as follows:

```
helloworld.dSYM

     Resources

          DWARF

               helloworld [A document]
     Info.plist

helloworld [A unix executable]

helloworld.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

The default `tasks.json` file in VSCode is something like:

```
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
```

To get rid of the dSYM directory you just have to add a `0` (zero) to the `-g` flag.

By specifying `-g0`, you are telling the compiler to generate minimal debug information or completely omit debug symbols. This will prevent the creation of dSYM files during the compilation process.

A simple example:

`clang++ -g0 -o output_file source_file.cpp`